# Connecting SonarCloud with bitbucket pipelines

Tags: sonarcloud, bitbucket-cloud

I am new to sonarcloud and would like to automate my code quality tests in bitbucket I am trying to use bitbucket pipelines to do it (I am new to pipelines too) my end goal is to do a branch analysis of codes and display the results in the bitbucket UI itself on trying to follow the steps in sonarcloud I came across these lines of codes and I am unclear what to add to allow the automating code check :

image: ************************** # Choose an image matching your project needs

clone:
depth: full              # SonarCloud scanner needs the full history to assign issues properly

definitions:
caches:
sonar: ~/.sonar/cache  # Caching SonarCloud artifacts will speed up your build
steps:
- step: &build-test-sonarcloud
name: Build, test and analyze on SonarCloud
caches:
- **************************           # See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html
- sonar
script:
- **************************           # Build your project and run
- pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.2.0
- step: &check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
name: Check the Quality Gate on SonarCloud
script:
- pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.4

pipelines:                 # More info here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html
branches:
master:
- step: *build-test-sonarcloud
- step: *check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
pull-requests:
'**':
- step: *build-test-sonarcloud
- step: *check-quality-gate-sonarcloud

Answer (score 0):

To set up SonarCloud with Bitbucket Pipelines, follow these steps:

Log in to your Bitbucket account.
Go to SonarCloud and set up an account. Create an organization to analyze your project. Once the organization is created, add the project from your Bitbucket repository. Grant access as required, and follow the instructions to set up Bitbucket Pipelines for CI/CD.
Click on "I need a pipeline" to proceed. You will receive a list of instructions specific to your chosen programming language. Follow them accordingly.
Enable pipelines in the repository settings. Set up Sonar tokens in the repository variables section.
Configure the pipeline according to the language you are using (e.g., JavaScript/TypeScript, Python, etc.).

Make sure to refer to the official documentation of SonarCloud and Bitbucket Pipelines for detailed instructions on setting up the integration.
https://docs.sonarcloud.io/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.